Linear algebra - normal operator
I was given the following problem :
Let $V$ be an inner-product space over $\mathbb{C}$ (complex numbers) and let $T : V\rightarrow V$ be a normal linear operator. Let us define a new operator $S : V\rightarrow V$ such that
$$S = (1+i)T + iT^*.$$
Prove $\ker S = \ker T$
i was able to prove that $\ker T \subset \ker S$ which is easy, by just multiplying both sides of the given equation by some $v \in \ker T$ but i can't seem to prove the opposite direction, would love some help on this one.

hi, can anyone help?

You already know that $T$ and $T^$ have the same kernel because $T$ is normal. The same holds for $S$ and $S^.$ Moreover, there is an invertible linear relationship between the pairs $(T,T^)$ and $(S,S^).$ Would that help?

why does the same hold for $S$? how do we know that $S$ is also a normal operator?

Write out the expression for $S^*$ and check by direct computation that it commutes with $S.$

ok,i understand. and what about that invertible linear relationship? how did you get that?

$S$ is a polynomial in $T$. Since $T$ is normal, so is $S$. Therefore $S$ and $S^\ast$ have the same kernel. Now suppose that $Sx=S^\ast x=0$. Write this out in terms of $Tx$ and $T^\ast x$ and continue from here...

@Carl the linear definition of $S$ in terms of $T$ and $T^$ is given, and you have worked out a linear expression of $S^$ in terms of $T$ and $T^.$ Solve that linear system for $T$ (and $T^$) and then use the same reasoning that gave you the other inclusion between kernels.

Diagonalize $T$ and $T^$ with unitary $U$.  This necessarily diagonalizes $S$ as well so check for zeros on its diagonal -- in each case reason they must be zeros on $T$ and $T^$ as well by triangle inequality.
